# InternetSetCookieEx InternetGetCookieEx Cookie Never / Always Expires

Tags: c#, cookies

i have a problem, i'm getting an headache with a C# code and a cookie that don't expire.

i'm using the following imported function

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, EntryPoint = "InternetGetCookieExW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        static extern bool InternetGetCookieEx([In]string lpszUrl, [In]string lpszCookieName, [Out] StringBuilder lpszCookieData, [In, Out] ref UInt32 lpdwSize, uint dwFlags, IntPtr lpReserved);

[DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, EntryPoint = "InternetSetCookieExW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        static extern bool InternetSetCookieEx([In]string lpszUrl, [In]string lpszCookieName, [In]string lpszCookieData, uint dwFlags, [In] IntPtr dwReserved);
```

and then i do

```
InternetSetCookieEx("http://localhost/index.php", null, "expiration=for+5+seconds; expires=Sun, 24-Mar-2019 20:16:35 GMT; path=/", 0, IntPtr.Zero)
```

and 10 seconds later i do

```
InternetGetCookieEx("http://localhost/index.php", null, lpszCookieData, ref lpdwzSize, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
```

But it doesn't work, i still getting the "expiration" cookie in my lpszCookieData result

Fun fact, this happen to me only when i use windows 7 (tested on 2 machines) but work well on windows 10

Any ideas about what i could do wrong ???
i also tried with InternetGetCookie & InternetSetCookie and got the same result.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**Edit:** changed the title from Never to Never / Always. Because after finding the solution, i understand that the problem could be different depending on where you are on Earth :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i finally found the solution

after doing this:

```
HttpWebResponse HttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)HttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

and reading `HttpWebResponse.Headers` where it result as :

```
Set-Cookie: expiration=for+5+seconds; expires=Mon, 25-Mar-2019 13:47:30 GMT; path=/
```

i noticed that the cookies stored in `HttpWebResponse.Cookies` has a `Cookie.Expires` based on the Machine DateTime `Mon, 25-Mar-2019 14:47:30 GMT` (like you would get with `DateTime.Now`) and not the UTC DateTime (ex: `DateTime.UtcNow`)

As i was building my cookie string value for `InternetSetCookieEx` based on `HttpWebResponse.Cookies`. I was then getting a + 1 hour (coz i'm in France) on the expires DateTime which is, in fact, supposed to be a UTC DateTime.

The solution was to convert it to UTC like so:

```
Values += "; expires=" + Cookie.Expires.ToUniversalTime().ToString("R");
```

My final tought is that there's must be some kind of correction in Windows 10 that don't exist for Windows 7 for `InternetSetCookieEx`. It migth automatically correct the expires time to UTC if the string containing the GTM DateTime is wrong.
(that's probably not exact, but you've got the idea)